# wxWidgets change keyboard input language

Tags: keyboard, wxwidgets

is there a function / class in wxwidgets that allows me to find out what keyboard layouts are installed and then change them?

I looked through the documentation and came across wxLanguage and wxKeyboardstate, but they don'T seem to be the answer.

Comment: Mh. Well I found this for windows: http://www.sheroz.com/articles/c-cpp/programmatically-switching-keyboard-layouts

in case anyone has a similar problem; I just hoped there is some cross plattform solution

Answer (score 0):

No. This is done using the standard system-global methods and wxWidgets doesn't provide access to it. FWIW `wxLanguage` is only used to select the locale to use and you can also retrieve the default user language, but not the keyboard layout.